# want to display 4 images in one row

Tags: php, mysql

this code is for retrieval of images from database,it do well with retrieval of images but i want to display 4 images in one row..and it show error on else condition. please anyone help me.

```
$page_title = 'animals';
include('includes/header.php'); 
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/secondary.css"/>


<?php
    $tbl_name=$db_prefix."images";
    $adjacents = 3;
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];
    $targetpage =$base_url . 'animal.php'; 
    $limit = 50; 

    if(!isset($_REQUEST['page']))
        { 
          $page=1;
            }
    else 
        {
            $page=$_REQUEST['page'];
        }

    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;  
        else
        $start = 0;


$query="SELECT image_id, image_name, image_desc, image_size, image_title FROM " . $tbl_name . " WHERE image_category IN (1)  LIMIT ".      $start.",". $limit;


$result=mysql_query($query) or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());

 if ($page == 0) $page = 1;
        $prev = $page - 1;
        $next = $page + 1;
        $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;
        $pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class='pagination'>";

         if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$prev'>Previous </a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>Previous </span>";    

            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))

            {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }


            }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))

        {
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)

                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }

            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {   
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1  </a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2  </a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";

                        else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";

                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }

            else
            {    
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1  </a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2  </a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)

                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">Next  </a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">Next  </span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }
?>
<?php echo $pagination; ?>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<p id="categoryheading">Animals</p>
<br />

<div id="searchphoto">
<table >




<?php 
$count=0;
do
{

?>
<tr>
<?php 
if($count==4)
{?>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 150; " >
<a href="animal_pg2.php?image_id=<?php echo base64_encode($row['image_id']); ?>"><img src="<?php echo  'thumbnail_images/' . $row['image_name'];?>"/></a>

</td>
<?php
$count++;   
    }
    ?>

<?php
else
{
    ?>
<td style="width: 150; " >
<a href="animal_pg2.php?image_id=<?php echo base64_encode($row['image_id']); ?>"><img src="<?php echo  'thumbnail_images/' . $row['image_name'];?>"/></a>
</td>
<?php
$count++;
?>

<?php
}
?>


 <input type="hidden" name="image_id" value="<?php echo $image_id; ?>" >



   <?php    
    }

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
?>
 </table>
<?php echo $pagination; ?>      


</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<?php include('includes/footer.php');?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You you have posted _way too much_ code for us to help effectively. Please trim it down to only the relevant parts or few are likely to read through it all.

Comment: there is many else . which one u mean or u want we look to all your code ?

Comment: Or perhaps give us a line number to look at and the exact error.

Comment: In general, if you can post a live demo of your code, it's very helpful. At the moment I am not sure what is happening, and readers won't be willing to install it on a LAMP server to try it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$page_title = 'animals';
include('includes/header.php'); 
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/secondary.css"/>


<?php
    $tbl_name=$db_prefix."images";
    $adjacents = 3;
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];
    $targetpage =$base_url . 'animal.php'; 
    $limit = 50; 

    if(!isset($_REQUEST['page']))
        { 
          $page=1;
            }
    else 
        {
            $page=$_REQUEST['page'];
        }

    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;  
        else
        $start = 0;


$query="SELECT image_id, image_name, image_desc, image_size, image_title FROM " . $tbl_name . " WHERE image_category IN (1)  LIMIT ".      $start.",". $limit;


$result=mysql_query($query) or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());

 if ($page == 0) $page = 1;
        $prev = $page - 1;
        $next = $page + 1;
        $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;
        $pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class='pagination'>";

         if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$prev'>Previous </a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>Previous </span>";    

            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))

            {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }


            }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))

        {
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)

                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }

            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {   
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1  </a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2  </a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";

                        else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";

                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }

            else
            {    
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1  </a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2  </a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)

                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">Next  </a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">Next  </span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }
?>
<?php echo $pagination; ?>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<p id="categoryheading">Animals</p>
<br />

<div id="searchphoto">
<table >




<?php 
$count=0;
do
{

?>
<tr>
<?php 
if($count==4)
{?>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 150; " >
<a href="animal_pg2.php?image_id=<?php echo base64_encode($row['image_id']); ?>"><img src="<?php echo  'thumbnail_images/' . $row['image_name'];?>"/></a>

</td>
<?php
$count++;   
    }

else
{
    ?>
<td style="width: 150; " >
<a href="animal_pg2.php?image_id=<?php echo base64_encode($row['image_id']); ?>"><img src="<?php echo  'thumbnail_images/' . $row['image_name'];?>"/></a>
</td>
<?php
$count++;
?>

<?php
}
?>


 <input type="hidden" name="image_id" value="<?php echo $image_id; ?>" >



   <?php    
    }

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
?>
 </table>
<?php echo $pagination; ?>      


</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<?php include('includes/footer.php');?>
```

Comment: it removes the error but problem is still it do not display 4 images in one row :(